# git diff reports changes, but I cannot get rid of them (not CRLF issues AFAICT)

Tags: git

I'm using `git bash` on Windows. `git diff` always reports that some files have been changed, but this appears not to be a CRLF issue - as you can see in the snapshot below, `git diff` shows actual file modifications on some lines, rather than just EOL changes. However, going various combinations of `git checkout`, `git rm --cached` and `git reset --hard` always results in the same diff showing up. What's going on?

If it helps to know, the repo I'm working in is huge - it's something like a 1GB checkout, and the changes all appear localised to a single directory, which totals 58MB, though only about 10 files within it show changes.

[image: section of diff showing actual changes]

Comment: One possibility, an issue I ran into on Macs which also have case-folding file systems: if there is a file FooBar.c and another one named foobar.c in the *same directory* (and the two files are very similar) you get this kind of behavior.  It's worth checking, at least.  (I didn't need to debug this, I just moved to a Unix box, so I'm not sure what all the preconditions for the bug are, except for filename-same-but-for-case.)

Comment: @torek oh wow, that appears to be the case. Thanks for that! I didn't even think that that there might be files named the same but for case. For example, browsing the folder, it contains `xt_hl.c`, but git is warning that `xt_HL.c` is modified. I might try using a Linux VM, though `git status` runs so slowly in a VM that I don't think it'll be helpful on balance. Guess I'll just have to tolerate it!

Comment: It might be worth experimenting with debugging it, if the VM is that slow. :-)  I think git is getting something wrong with its core.ignorecase code - for instance, on a case-preserving but case-folding system, it could unlink the file and then re-create it in the newly-correct case, if that's (part of?) the problem.